# How to enable task dependencies in org mode?

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs

The org mode readme says that [task dependencies](https://develop.spacemacs.org/layers/%2Bemacs/org/README.html#todo-dependencies) can be enabled by using:

```
(setq-default dotspacemacs-configuration-layers '(
  (org :variables
       org-todo-dependencies-strategy 'naive-auto)))
```

I tried adding this inside my `(defun dotspacemacs/user-init ()` and also `(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()`, but in either case the parent tasks in my todo list are not grayed out.

Where exactly should I insert the above snippet?

Comment: The documentation you link to is for the development version of Spacemacs. Are you using that version? If not, there is a link on the page to the released version, but AFAICT,  that version does not seem to know about `org-todo-dependencies-strategy` yet. You might want to add to your question the version of Spacemacs that you are using.

Comment: @NickD Well, I cloned the spacemacs repo into my emacs config so it would have used the `develop` branch. Looking at my `layers/+emacs/org/README.org` file, I see that it has the header about dependencies (and `master` indeed does not).

Answer (score 1):

In fact you should put

```
(org :variables
       org-todo-dependencies-strategy 'naive-auto)
```

in `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers` rather than `dotspacemacs/user-init` or `dotspacemacs/user-config`.